# Trouble scraping data out of a table from a webpage

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I've written a script in python in combination with selenium to scrape data from a certain table located within a webpage (finance.yahoo). However, when I execute it I get an error. I can't find out if there is any mistake I have made in it. FYC, what I've written so far is pasted below.

Script I'm trying with:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get("https://finance.yahoo.com/")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "table.tbl tbody")))
items = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("table.tbl tbody")
list_of_data = [[item.text for item in data.find_elements_by_css_selector('td')]
                    for data in items.find_elements_by_css_selector('tr')]
for tab_data in list_of_data:
    print(tab_data) 

driver.quit()
```

The error my script throws:

```
line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

Partial portion of the elements in which the data of the table are:

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%" class="tbl">
                <tbody>
                    <tr><th class="pr">Loan Type</th><th class="rate">Today</th><th class="ch">Change</th><th class="lw">Last&nbsp;Week</th></tr>
                    <tr class="">
                        <td class="pr"><a target="_top" rel="nofollow" href="https://finance.yahoo.com/rates">30 yr fixed</a></td>
                        <td class="rate">3.82%</td>
                        <td class="ch"><div class="arrow-up"></div></td>
                        <td class="lw">3.80%</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="bk ">
                        <td class="pr"><a target="_top" rel="nofollow" href="https://finance.yahoo.com/rates/mortgage/15-year-fixed">15 yr fixed</a></td>
                        <td class="rate">3.01%</td>
                        <td class="ch"><div class="arrow-down"></div></td>
                        <td class="lw">3.05%</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

Comment: increase the timeout

Comment: Thanks Gaurang Shah, for your suggestion. Increased the time and executed but no luck. Still having the same error.

Comment: check if element is inside any frame

Comment: I din't find any element as `(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "table.tbl tbody")` on `https://finance.yahoo.com/` Thanks. Whats your exact manual step? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the Answer to your Question:

Looking at the HTML you provided, I assume you are trying to scrape the table **`Rates`** which have table headers as `Loan Type`, `Today`, `Change` and `Last Week`. But I am still not sure in which format you wanted the data to be scrapped.

The **`Rates`** table is within an `iframe` by the name **`bankrate-overnight-average`**. So we need to switch to the frame first and then scrape the table. Here is the working code block to scrape the **`Rates`** table with your scrapping logic unchanged:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_argument("disable-infobars")
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=r'C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get("https://finance.yahoo.com/")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.NAME, "bankrate-overnight-average")))
items = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("table.tbl tbody")
list_of_data = [[item.text for item in data.find_elements_by_css_selector('td')]
            for data in items.find_elements_by_css_selector('tr')]
for tab_data in list_of_data:
    print(tab_data)
```

The output on my console reads as:

```
[]
['30 yr fixed', '3.82%', '', '3.80%']
['15 yr fixed', '3.01%', '', '3.05%']
['30 yr fixed refi', '3.80%', '', '3.77%']
['15 yr fixed refi', '2.97%', '', '3.02%']
['30 yr jumbo', '4.04%', '', '4.06%']
['5/1 ARM refi', '3.25%', '', '3.23%']
```

Let me know if this Answers your Question.

Comment: Oh my god!!! You did it finally. Thanks DebanjanB for your effective answer. I'm gonna take out my answer. Btw, could you give me a one liner explanation--what was wrong with my script when i tried to parse the same table with the class "tbl" but couldn't. Thanks. Gonna accept your answer in a while.

Comment: @Shahin Glad to be able to help you :) `with your scrapping logic unchanged`

Comment: Yep it is indeed. Btw, seeing your answer I found that it could also be achieved using a one liner--driver.switch_to_frame("bankrate-overnight-average") .Thanks a lot once again.

Comment: @Shahin There is a point. Accessing `https://finance.yahoo.com/` involves a lot of JavaScript & AJAX calls, so we are not sure if the availability of the intended `frame` would occur before or after achieving `document.ready` state = `complete`. Hence I took the proven path.

Answer (score 0):

I visited the url and checked the page elements and there is no table element with className as 'tbl' which is why the driver is not able to locate the element and timing out. Just try and remove the .tbl from the following lines:

```
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "table.tbl tbody")))
items = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("table.tbl tbody")
```

Also since items would be a list object, the method find_elements_by_css_selector() will not be applicable to it and you might get an error because of that.

Comment: Thanks Anoop Sharma for your answer. if i try what you said I get the data from the first table which is blank then setting the table index in my script i get the second and so on. However, I want to scrape that specific table i mentioned above. FYI, if you look at the above element, you will see there is a class named "tbl". Thanks again.